# UIView Background Image Not Scaling on Device Rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

I'm giving a view a background image with `[[self myView] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];`.

It looks fine until rotating the device. It doesn't seem to scale and stays its original size.

If I change to a different view and back again via the Tab Bar, it will now be scaled properly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: tried playing around with the contentMode property of the view?

Comment: I've tried Redraw and Scale to Fill, and a few others. I didn't notice any affect with any of them.

Comment: Actually, if I change views and then back again, I can see the various effects of the contentMode property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who wrote suggesting resetting the frame, thanks your idea helped. I don't know why you erased your answer.

I added a line of code in each rotation block, something like this: `[[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,x,y);`

The background image now scales properly.